# Calling a method from within itself is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a method again from within itself after a period of time, but it isn't working.

I have the the following:

```
Hi.prototype.stuff = function(){
    console.log("hello")
    setTimeout(()=>this.stuff(), 1000)
}
```

However, it outputs "hello" to the console only once. It should output "hello" twice. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How are you calling `Hi`?

Comment: Create `const __this = this;` before function starts and then use `__this` inside the function.

Comment: The code you show does not log anything.

Comment: @connexo oh, derp.. I was testing the wrong file and thought it was logging for the file I created for this question. Dang up arrow.. The answer posted is helping me sort things out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you declare and instanciate `Hi` correctly? This seems to work:

```js
function Hi(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Hi.prototype.stuff = function() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
  setTimeout(() => this.stuff(), 1000);
};

const x = new Hi('Dshiz');
x.stuff();
```

Comment: Hum.. I guess I didn't realize Hi should have also been a function. One question though, shouldn't `setTimeout` only execute `this.stuff()` once? Your code snippet is behaving more like `setInterval`

Comment: @Dshiz that is because it is calling itself via setTimeout, which in turn, calls itself, which in turn calls itself, which in turn calls itself, which... you get the idea.

Comment: @Reality, got it.. that makes sense... I'll add a counter or something to stop it from running more than once.

Answer (score 2):

How are you calling the function?

```
function Hi() {

}
Hi.prototype.stuff = function(){
    console.log("hello")
    setTimeout(()=>this.stuff(), 1000)
}

Hi.prototype.stuff();
```

works for me.

Comment: Thank you.. I wrote code into a new file for this question and realized I was missing a few things because I wasn't running the right file.. oops.